# Sql Server is rounding the value while calculating average

Tags: sql-server, ceil

I am trying to calculate average and the apply CEILING on the average, but somehow when i calculate average it is always rounding off the value.

```
DECLARE @AverageStudents INT
SELECT @AverageStudents = CEILING((SELECT @TotalUsersInAllScools + @TotalUsersInAllColleges AS FLOAT) + (SELECT @TotalSchools + @TotalUsersColleges AS FLOAT))
SELECT @AverageStudents AS 'AverageStudents'
```

In my case `@TotalUsersInAllScools + @TotalUsersInAllColleges = 875` , and `@TotalSchools + @TotalUsersColleges = 216`

875/216 = 4.0509 and CEILING of it should give me output 5 but its giving 4.

What i observed is `@TotalUsersInAllScools + @TotalUsersInAllColleges AS FLOAT) + (SELECT @TotalSchools + @TotalUsersColleges AS FLOAT)`is giving output as 4

Comment: What are the datatypes of  your variables. I bet they are an `int`.

Comment: yeah they are INT

Comment: An expression that uses an `int` returns an `int`, so it would be impossible to return `4.0509`. `875/216=4` when you were dealing with `int`s.